# Cannot Delete Outlook 2013 Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am attempting to delete a Folder in Outlook 2013 which was related to a secondary exchange email box.

When right-clicking the top level folder for the email I select **Close "folderxxx"**.  I then receive this message.

```
This group of folders is associated with an e-mail account.  
To remove the account, click the File Tab, and on the Info tab, 
click Account Settings.  Select the e-mail account, and then 
click Remove
```

The problem is that I already have done that and this particular email address is not longer listed in the e-mail tab of the Account Settings.

It seems Outlook thinks it is there but now I have no idea how to rid myself of this folder.

Thanks for any help you can provide.